# %timeit statement1; statement2;

Tags: python, ipython, timeit

In IPython, when working with the magic [`%timeit`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions) does

> %timeit statement1; statement2;

measure `statement1` or `statement1` and `statement2` together (sequentially)? I would like to measure the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Both statements. You can confirm using the `sleep` function from the `time` module:

```
In [4]: %timeit time.sleep(1); time.sleep(5)
1 loops, best of 3: 6 s per loop
```